# How solve slow througput with blocking call in SpringBoot2?

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, project-reactor, throughput

I use Spring Boot 2 and Router Function and all fine if haven't blocking code, but if I have block for 2 seconds - awfully. My application can't reach huge numbers of concurrent users and I can't impove throughput.

Doc have a section [How do I wrap a synchronous, blocking call](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking) , but this approach doesn't solve the problem.

I created simple springboot2 applications where recreated the problem.

```
    return serverRequest
            .bodyToMono(ValueDto.class)
            .doOnNext(order -> log.info("get order request " + order))
            .map(i -> {
                log.info("map 1 " + requestId);
                return i;
            })
            .map(i -> {
                log.info("map 2 " + requestId);
                return i;
            })
            .map(i -> {
                log.info("map 3 " + requestId);
                return i;
            })
            .flatMap(i -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> executeLongMethod(i, requestId))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()))
            .map(v -> {
                log.info("map 5 " + requestId);
                return v;
            })
            .flatMap(req -> ServerResponse.ok().build());


private ValueDto executeLongMethod(final ValueDto dto, final String requestId) {
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        log.info("start executeLongMethod. requestId:" + requestId);


        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1500);

        return dto;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return dto;
    } finally {
        log.info("finish executeLongMethod requestId:" + requestId + " executed in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms.");
    }
}
```

Perform Automated Load Testing through Jmeter. It Settings:

ThreadGroup:

Number of Threads: number of concurrent threads to run during the test : **30**

Ramp-Up Period: linear increase the load from 0 to target load over this time: **1**

Loop Count: **forever**

Post request: {
"valueA":"fake",
"valueB":"fake",
"valueC":"fake"
}

Results:
[image]

Code samples can be found [over on GitHub.](https://github.com/MaximDzhezhelo/fakeReceiver.git)

Comment: Don't use `Thread.sleep`... Sleep in a non-blocking way (use `delayElement` for that). With this you are blocking the processing and.or request handling thread or even potentially your whole reactive threads leading you to a halt.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case `Thread.sleep` - example. I can call soap or other blocking operation. I  tried `.flatMap(i ->Mono.just(i).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(1500)))` but it didn't improve throughput.

Comment: If all available threads are blocked then of course nothing will happen. Eventually everything will be blocked and generally with a reactive approach you have less threads to do the same amount of work.

Comment: @ M. Deinum of course blocking APIs are not a good fit for this concurrency model. But when chain call `Schedulers.elastic()` - it  continue processing on a different thread because switch processing to a different thread pool. I thought it could improve situation.

Comment: How many CPUs do you have?

Comment: @M. Deinum 
CPU(s):                4
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             2